# HABTM assosiation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models User and Project

User  ->  has_many :projects ,:dependent=>:destroy

Project -> has_and_belongs_to_many :users

I also created a mapping table projects_users.

When i tried to delete user its corresponding projects are not deleting from projects table ,and mapping table also shows same data without change ,only thing happening is my user data is deleting.

Is there any way to delete associated data ,and to remove entries from mapping table.

Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name ,:user_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :projects 
end
```

AssosiationTable

```
class ProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :projects_users, :id => false do |t|

        t.references :project
        t.references :user
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :projects_users
  end
end
```

User:  _form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user  do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :name %>
     <% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
  <% end %>
```

Project:  _form.html.erb

```
<%= semantic_form_for @project  do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :name %>
     <%= f.input :users, :as => :check_boxes %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the code causing the problem (where the deletion occurs)?

Comment: I have created Project and User through scaffolding, when i tried to delete user its associated projects are not deleting .